# I'm having a problem in Python with Dictionary and Map Functions

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, data-analysis

I want to ask how should I edit this for my table to show up. I'm using Python 3.7 through Spyder and this is my first major problem in Python

```
recode2={1:1.5,2:4.5,3:9,4:12,5:30,6:52,7:104,8:182,9:360, 10:365}
sub2a['DRINKBEERNEWFR']=sub2['S2AQ5B'].map(recode2)
sub2b=sub2a['DRINKBEERNEWFR'].copy()

print('Counts for DRINKBEERNEWFR')
c7=sub2b.value_counts(sort=False,dropna=False)
print(c7)
```

For reference "S2AQ5B" is the question code and I want to change the answers from integers to intervals hence the dictionaries. What should appear in the console is a new frequency table with the new values and amount of times the respondents answered a choice.

*Should look something like this:*

```
Counts for DRINKBEERNEWFR
6      113
5       88
7       75
4       74
10      74
3       58
9       47
8       32
1       20
2       17
NaN      3
```

Can I get some help?

Comment: Not bad! But the fluff needs to go in a comment instead of the post :)

Comment: What is `sub2` and `sub2a`? In your code you use it, but we don't see the definition anywhere.

Comment: @Matthias it's a new name I want to use in order to combine both the recoded answers in the dictionary and the question of S2AQ5B into a frequency table

Comment: Could you provide an example that we can run?